# Giving SQL Sever access to connect to a a network share - no domain

Tags: sql-server, nas, network-share, qnap

I have a QNAP nas and I want to give my SQL Server 2019 access to a share on the server.  The NAS is linux based and not part of a domain.

I simply want to give my SQL server credentials to use when connecting to that share.

**How can I do this?**

I'm thinking it might be a proxy but I've never set one up before.

Background: My stored procedures retrieves file details on the server.

Answer (score 0):

(this should be comment, not answer,  but don't have enough points)  Can you access the OS on the NAS?  If so this wouldn't be set up with SQL Server Proxy but as a windows folder linked to the linux share (setup with samba or similar).   Then ensure the service account that SQL Server is running under has access to the windows folder (that's really linked to your linux nas).     Your NAS provider might already have this functionality built in, might want to check with them.

What is the goal of the SQL Server 2019 accessing the linux folder?  for backups?  You probably already know but SQL Server 2019 installs on linux quite easily. I've installed on debian, centOS and amazon linux without issue.

Comment: I have a windows credential for the nas on the server so i can see all the folders on the nas without prompting for a password.  I have some code reading file metadata which works fine.   However on 1 server (linux based) i get a credentials issue.  I don't know how to get SQL to pass credentials on servers that are not on the domain.